# Calculate the mean of mean ratings in R uni homework

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi sorry for the vague title, not sure what to put as haven't used R much.
I've put below what my university wants me to do and my attempt at it.

I believe I've done the first three things (but not sure please check), but I'm struggling with the last thing (then for each gender group calculate the mean of those mean ratings).

Thanks sorry for the mess, hope it is understandable enough to offer assistance :).

What I have to do:

only keep participants aged 19 to 24

only keep age, gender, and romantic orientation ratings

for each person, calculate the mean rating across the three romatnic orientation ratings

then for each gender group calculate the mean of those mean ratings

My attempt:

```
     gensex %>%
  dplyr::filter (age< 24) %>%
dplyr::select(gender,romantic_strength,age,romantic_freq,romantic_gender) %>%
dplyr::group_by(gender) %>%
dplyr::summarise(
  mean_romstr = mean(romantic_strength, na.rm=TRUE),
  mean_romfreq = mean(romantic_freq),
  mean_romgen = mean(romantic_gender),
  
  mean_gender = mean(gender),
 
)
```

[image of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p540m.png)

Cannot include expected output as I do not have any more information except the instructions on what to do.

New code

````
```{r}
library(tidyverse)

gensex %>% 
  dplyr::filter (between (x= age, left = 19, right = 24)) %>%
dplyr::select(age,gender,contains('romantic'))%>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(mean_rating = mean(romantic_strength, romantic_freq, romantic_gender)) %>%
group_by(gender) %>%
summarize (grand_mean= mean(mean_rating, na.rm=TRUE)) 



  
```
````

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and your expected output

Answer (score 0):

With the information you gave following steps have to carried out:

```r
# load all tidyverse-functions
# make explicit calls like 'dplyr::' unnecessary
library(tidyverse)

# from your dataframe
gensex %>%

# only keep participants aged 19 to 24 (19 and 24 yr old's included)
filter(between(x = age, left = 19, right = 24)) %>%

# only keep age, gender, and romantic orientation ratings
# all variables that have word "romatic" are kept
select(age, gender, contains('romantic')) %>%

# for each person, calculate the mean rating across the three romatnic orientation ratings
# we have to tell R that we want to perform an operation on rows
rowwise() %>%
mutate(mean_rating = mean(romantic_strength, romantic_freq, romantic_gender))

# then for each gender group ...
group_by(gender) %>%

# ... calculate the mean of those mean ratings
summarize(grand_mean = mean(mean_rating))
```

If you have missing values in your data (`NA`) an additional argument to mean may help you, so for example: `grand_mean = mean(mean_rating, na.rm = TRUE)`

As akrun mentioned, a reproducible example is helpful.

Comment: Thank you especially for the description on each line. Does mutate add another row with the mean of the values listed after? 99% sure, but just making sure.  I've included a ss in the op of the ds. Added the new code to the Op

Comment: Mutate creates a new column (as default appended as the last column). That column holds the row mean of the three variables, that is the value for each person.